# Caching ajax results

Tags: ajax, json, caching

I have an ajax call that retrieves lines from file via json.

The results retreived via json I wanted to cache, so that if a data is requested more than once, I will not send request again. what is the best practices for caching in jquery? How do I go about it?

I use php in my server side.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.ajax(url, {cache: true}) will tell the browser to cache the request. In fact, cache defaults to true unless the **dataType** setting is set to **script** or **jsonp**. In other words, you can probably use jQuery.ajax(url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995875/how-to-cache-the-result-of-post-request-in-jquery i actually saw this and thought this is usef useful.. but i dont get the callback part.. and the data parameter of getInfo()..